# Haskell: How to unwrap the value in a Seq?

Tags: haskell, sequence, monads

I wanted to put an element in the middle of a list so I did:

```
update myPosition myValue $ fromList myList
```

Now, I have a type of `Seq a` but I need the whole list of `a` (`[a]`). How can I extract the value from this line to return the whole list with `myValue` in it?

`Seq` is from `Data.Sequence`.

Comment: Can you identify what `Seq` type you are talking about specifically? Assuming that it contains multiple elements, which element do you want?

Comment: It is a Seq Int. I want the whole list.

Comment: I mean what package/module did `Seq` come from. Also, if you want the whole list that would be `[a]` not `a` as your question suggests. [Please edit the question to add the extra details I and anyone else asks for, so it makes sense without having to read the comments]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Seq` from `Data.Sequence` is an instance of `Foldable`, so you can use [`toList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v%3atoList) from `Data.Foldable` to convert it to a list.

Comment: This appears to do what I needed. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean [Data.Sequence.Seq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#5), in which case you can use one of the functions for indexing:

- index :: Seq a -> Int -> a